# Directed graph decomposition

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to decompose a directed acyclic graph into minimum number of components such that in each component the following property holds true-
For all pair of vertices (u,v) in a components, there is a path from u to v **or** from v to u.

Is there any algorithm for this?

I know that when the or is replaced by **and** in the condition, it is same as finding the number of strongly connected components(which is possible using DFS).

***EDIT: *** What happens if the Directed graph contains cycles (i.e. it is not acyclic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is to order the graph topologically O(n) using DFS, and then think about for what vertices can this property be false. It can be false for those who are joining from 2 different branches, or who are spliting into 2 different branches.

I would go from any starting vertex(lowest in topological ordering) and follow it's path going into random branches, till you cannot go further and delete this path from graph(first component).This would be repeated till the graph is empty and you have all such components.

It seems like a greedy algorithm, but consider you find a very short path in the first run(by having a random bad luck) or you find a longest path(good luck). Then you would still have to find that small branch component in another step of algorithm.

Complexity would be O(n*number of components).

When there is **and** condition, you should be considering any oriented graph, as DAG cannot have strongly connected component.

Comment: Thanks you Mark Seygan for for quick answer. It was useful and informative

Comment: It seems that your algorithm can only produce *paths* as components -- but there can easily be non-path subgraphs (e.g., cycles) that satisfy the OP's condition.

Comment: I don't get the idea of getting cycle subgraph from a directed-acyclic-graph meeting that condition. Can you please specify?

Comment: I mean if there was a part of graph for whose every two vertices were connected by directed edge, it would't be DAG.

Comment: Sorry, cycles were a bad example -- I missed that the question was (originally) only about DAGs (I was maybe confused by the OP's suggestion of finding strongly connected components; the only SCCs in a DAG are the individual vertices).  Still, you can get components that satisfy the OP's condition but are not paths *or* cycles: E.g., take n vertices, number them from 1 to n, and create a directed edge from every lower-numbered vertex to every higher-numbered vertex.  This graph is cycle-free, is not a path (for n > 2), and satisfies the OP's condition.

Comment: Apologies, it seems I misunderstood the OP's question (see my bottommost comment on my own answer).  I'll think about your answer again.

Answer (score 0):

The two existing answers both have problems that I've outlined in comments.  But there's a more fundamental reason why no decomposition into components can work in general.  First, let's concisely express the relation "u and v belong in the same component of the decomposition" as u # v.

### It's not transitive

In order to represent a relation # as vertices in a component, that relation must be an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), which means among other things that it must [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation):  That is, if x # y and y # z, it must necessarily be true that x # z.  Is our relation # transitive?  Unfortunately the answer is "No", since it may be that there is a path from x to y (so that x # y), and a path from z to y (so that y # z), but no path from x to z or from z to x (so that x # z *does not* hold), as the following graph shows:

```
       z
       |
       |
       v
x----->y
```

The problem is that according to the above graph, x and y belong in the same component, and y and z belong in the same component, but x and z belong in *different* components, which is a contradiction.  This means that, in general, it's impossible to represent the relationship # as a decomposition into components.

### If an instance happens to be transitive

So there is no solution *in general* -- but there can still be input graphs for which the relation # happens to be transitive, and for which we can therefore compute a solution.  Here is one way to do that (though probably not the most efficient way).

Compute shortest paths between all pairs of vertices (using e.g. the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), in O(n^3) time for n vertices).  Now, for every vertex pair (u, v), either d(u, v) = inf, indicating that there is no way to reach v from u at all, or not, indicating that there is some path from u to v.  To answer the question "Does u # v hold?" (i.e., "Do u and v belong in the same component of the decomposition?"), we can simply calculate `d(u, v) != inf || d(v, u) != inf`.

This gives us a relation that we can use to build an *undirected* graph G' in which there is a vertex u' for each original vertex u, and an edge between two vertices u' and v' if and only if `d(u, v) != inf || d(v, u) != inf`.  Intuitively, every connected component in this new graph must be a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29).  This property can be checked in O(n^2) time by first performing a series of DFS traversals from each vertex to assign a component label to each vertex, and then checking that each pair of vertices belongs to the same component if and only if they are connected by an edge.  If the property holds then the resulting cliques correspond to the desired decomposition; otherwise, there is no valid decomposition.

Interestingly, there are graphs that are not chains of strongly connected components (as [claimed by Zotta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33607372/47984)), but which nonetheless do have transitive # relations.  For example, a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29) is a digraph in which there is an edge, in some direction, between every pair of vertices -- so clearly # holds for every pair of vertices in such a graph.  But if we number the vertices 1 to n and include only edges from lower-numbered to higher-numbered vertices, there will be no cycles, and thus the graph is not strongly connected (and if n > 2, then clearly it's not a path).

Comment: how do you apply the last part of algorithm for clique property? (eg how to assign component label to each vertex etc.)

Comment: For example- consider a directed graph 0->2, 1->2, 1->4 and 2->3.

Comment: Just start a DFS from each vertex that visits only vertices that have not been seen by any DFS yet.  The first DFS labels every vertex that it visits with label 1, the second DFS with label 2, etc.  Each DFS will find an entire component and assign every vertex in it the same label.  Clear now?

Comment: After every vertex u' in G' has been assigned a component label comp[u'] by the previous step, you can just loop through all pairs of vertices u', v' in G', checking that there is an edge between u' and v' if and only if comp[u'] == comp[v'].

Comment: according to your answer the example given above by me must have no decomposition as the directed graph is not transitive. But a decomposition exists 0->2->3 ans 1->4. In each decomposition the condition "For all pair of vertices (u,v) in a components, there is a path from u to v or from v to u." exists. Please clarify.

Comment: Edge 1->2 in the input graph implies that vertices 1 and 2 should be in the same component of any solution, but they aren't in your solution.

Comment: But you're correct in saying that your example has *no* valid decomposition.

Comment: May be My question framed is bit ambiguous then. The solution mentioned by me is correct as given in the assignment solutions. May be partitioning the graph would be the right word as 1->2 does not necessary imply 1 and 2 should be in the same component. Or may be the conclusion drawn by me from assignment question is wrong.

Comment: Here I basically mean remove all the edges already present in the graph. The edges should be added such that when all the vertices in a component are ordered, there is an edge between them(present initially in the original graph). So in the above example there is no way it could be done in 1 component. 2 components were required which are given above. One more example(as given in our figure) means the x->y ans z(alone) world be the 2 components or x(alone) and z->y would be the second component.

Comment: Ah, it seems I misinterpreted your question.  I interpreted "For all pair of vertices (u,v) in a components, there is a path from u to v or from v to u" to mean "For all pair of vertices (u,v) in a components, there is a path from u to v or from v to u *in the original input graph*".  According to my new understanding, there's *always* some decomposition.  Will think about the new problem.